# MYSQL: Conditional counting of course enrolments with joined 1:N course categories?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, subquery

I've spent way too long thinking about the title of this question, so I hope the one I chose is kinda understandable. But let me explain:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `course` (`course_id`, `course_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Course A'),
(2, 'Course B'),
(3, 'Course C'),
(4, 'Course D'),
(5, 'Course E');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course_category` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `course_category` (`course_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 2),
(3, 1),
(3, 3),
(5, 1),
(5, 3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enrolment` (
  `enrolment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`enrolment_id`, `course_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 0),
(4, 3, 0),
(5, 3, 0),
(6, 3, 0),
(7, 4, 1),
(8, 4, 1),
(9, 4, 1),
(10, 4, 0);


ALTER TABLE `course`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`);

ALTER TABLE `enrolment`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`enrolment_id`);

ALTER TABLE `course`
  MODIFY `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=9;

ALTER TABLE `enrolment`
  MODIFY `enrolment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

**Fiddle:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dc3bgfMS5jTxE7wmp3SJ/0

```
# Table `course`
+-----------+-------------+
| course_id | course_name |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | Course A    |
|         2 | Course B    |
|         3 | Course C    |
|         4 | Course D    |
|         5 | Course E    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

```
# Table `course_category`
+-----------+-------------+
| course_id | category_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           1 |
|         1 |           2 |
|         1 |           3 |
|         2 |           2 |
|         3 |           1 |
|         3 |           3 |
|         5 |           1 |
|         5 |           3 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

```
# Table `enrolment`
+--------------+-----------+--------+
| enrolment_id | course_id | status |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
|            1 |         1 |      0 |
|            2 |         1 |      1 |
|            3 |         1 |      0 |
|            4 |         3 |      0 |
|            5 |         3 |      0 |
|            6 |         3 |      0 |
|            7 |         4 |      1 |
|            8 |         4 |      1 |
|            9 |         4 |      1 |
|           10 |         4 |      0 |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

(There's also a `category` table, but that's not important for the question.)

**I am trying to get the following result:**

1. All courses have to be in the result set
2. The category IDs of each course have to be a single string, separated by commas
3. The total number of enrolments whose status is 1 should be counted per course (Bear in mind that "1" is only an example here, it could also be another number or a string to be checked against)

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| course_name | category_ids | enrolments |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Course A    | 3,1,2        |          1 |
| Course B    | 2            |          0 |
| Course C    | 1,3          |          0 |
| Course D    | NULL         |          3 |
| Course E    | 1,3          |          0 |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

I have tried using `SUM` with a condition and `COUNT` with the `DISTINCT` keyword and a `WHERE` condition, but I can't get to have all the necessary points fulfilled.

**Experiment with `COUNT`:**

```
SELECT 
    course_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id) AS category_ids,
    COUNT(DISTINCT enrolment_id) as enrolments
FROM 
    course
LEFT JOIN course_category USING (course_id)
LEFT JOIN enrolment USING (course_id)
WHERE status = 1 OR status IS NULL
GROUP BY course_id

+-------------+--------------+------------+
| course_name | category_ids | enrolments |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Course A    | 3,1,2        |          1 |
| Course D    | NULL         |          3 |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

In this case I only get the course if at least one enrolment with status = 1 or no enrolment for the course exists, otherwise the whole course is missing in the result.

**Experiment with `SUM`:**

```
SELECT 
    course_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id) AS category_ids,
    SUM(IF(status=1,1,0)) as enrolments
FROM 
    course
LEFT JOIN course_category USING (course_id)
LEFT JOIN enrolment USING (course_id)
GROUP BY course_id

+-------------+--------------+------------+
| course_name | category_ids | enrolments |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Course A    | 3,1,2        |          3 |
| Course B    | 2            |          0 |
| Course C    | 1,3          |          0 |
| Course D    | NULL         |          3 |
| Course E    | 1,3          |          0 |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

In this case all the courses are there, but the counting is wrong, since I am not able to count distinct enrolments.

Which apporach am I missing?

Comment: Provide source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (or as online fiddle), please.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, added a fiddle.

Comment: *Bare in mind* I prefer to keep my mental clothes on, thanks.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the laugh! Also for the recommendation. I'd love to change the application code accordingly, but sadly that's not under my control. It expects the result to already be prepared in a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.course_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(cc.category_id ORDER BY cc.category_id) category_ids,
       COALESCE(e.status, 0) enrolments
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN course_category cc USING (course_id)
-- calculate statuses per course separately
LEFT JOIN (SELECT course_id, SUM(status) status   -- maybe SUM(status=1)?
           FROM enrolment 
           GROUP BY course_id ) e USING (course_id)
GROUP BY c.course_name, e.status
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dc3bgfMS5jTxE7wmp3SJ/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be simpler expressed with correlated subqueries rather than outer aggregation:

```
select c.course_name,
    (
        select group_concat(cc.category_id order by cc.category_id)
        from course_category cc
        where cc.course_id = c.course_id
    ) category_ids,
    (
        select coalesce(sum(e.status), 0)
        from enrolment e
        where e.course_id = c.course_id
    ) enrolments
from course c
order by c.course_name
```